# Youtube API Videos playing locally but not online

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Hey I am using the Youtube API to play embedded videos by random. It is working perfectly locally but when uploaded to my webserver, the videos don't play anymore.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="embed-container">
    <div id="player"></div>
</div>
```

and my javascript to play it:

```
// Youtube Player
// create youtube player
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {    
        videoId: 'P2jViqMnnK4',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
            'onError': onError,
        },
        playerVars: {
            'controls': 0,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'iv_load_policy': 3,
            'wmode': "opaque",
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Try looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303795/youtube-iframe-onyoutubeplayerapiready-not-called

Comment: i tried the window. function. It did not work :(

Comment: If it's all your JS code and if it really works on localhost, it seems that you didn't paste all required JS code from localhost to your new web server, because you missed to load the IFrame Player API and implement `onPlayerRady`, `onPlayerStateChange` and `onError` functions. Check out the official documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference (at least Getting started example).

Comment: I´m sorry, i forgot to mention that this is just an excerpt of my code. Of course i´ve implemented onplayerrdy onplayerstatechange etc. i will edit this ty

Comment: like i said, it works perfectly on localhost and i´ve uploaded everything so it should work. For example, it works in opera as well, but not in firefox or chrome

Comment: Hmm... I've tested your code both on localhost and web server, ff/opera/chrome. It works just fine. Is there any errors in JS console?

Comment: i´ve build a jsfiddle, this code works on localhost perfectly. but in the jsfiddle nothing happens, or did i foget something? http://jsfiddle.net/Dk4Ld/2/

Comment: It seems you didn't load API correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/Dk4Ld/4/ should work. All I did is add `<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>` to HTML code and change Frameworks & Extensions load method from `onload` to `no wrap - in <head>`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately it isn´t working in Chrome or IE if i upload it to my webserver like that. What is different in jsfiddle?

Comment: Ok it is working, but only after a few times reloading the site like 4-5 times :/

Comment: Not an expert yet, just started learning JS few weeks ago :) But I'm sure that it's all about asynchronous loading issue. Chrome didn't work well for me too, the "dirty hack" I've used for JavaScript Player API is to copy all external JS code directly to my code (in my case it's swfobject.js). Not sure if it will work with Iframe API (I did't use this API because it doesn't work in IE7 as official requirements says, and it doesn't work in Opera as well, at least for me).

Comment: few weeks ago??Feeling so bad right now. Anyway, i don´t know what´s the problem.. Would maybe something like a polyfill help? Thats funny, it works in opera for me but not in IE and Chrome :/ i really need to get this done.

Comment: I copied the YT API Code into my js file. Did you mean that? It works now in firefox,chrome,safari and opera. But not in IE :D i´m hating IE so much lol

Comment: Actually, I'm using JS for quite a long time, but started to *learn* it just now (via JavaScript: The Definitive Guide book, the best one on JS IMHO) =) Yep, I copied external JS to my js file too, and it works fine (but anyway, it's not good and I'll fix it someday...) Do you use IE8+? In IE7 and lower it shouldn't work (as official documentation stated). PS Tested it in IE10, works just fine.

Comment: I am using IE 10.. Maybe i should use another solution for my project. Basically i want to play different youtube videos randomly from a list like a xml file or something i can edit easily.. A shame it finally won´t work on all browsers :/

Comment: I think using youtube API is only one choice if it's necessary to load new video when current one ended :(

Comment: PS If after current video ends nothing should happen, then it's much easier http://jsfiddle.net/J82Fp/

Comment: It does not load another video after the first one has finished in the fiddle, doesn´t it? But i´ll give this a try as well ty

Comment: Yes, without using YouTube API we can't detect when current video is ended. But it's not a bad choice as a placeholder (if it should be done right now) until the final version based on youtube API will be finished which could take a while ;)

Comment: yeah that is not an option :D who know when it will be updated haha. I will keep on trying.. if it won´t work i will maybe use another player

Comment: I experienced the same issue. I solved it by changing api protocol http:// youtube.com/iframe_api. to https:// youtube.com/iframe_api  Note the (HTTPS://) ..Then i cleared my browser cache